# To prove $a_n = \frac{2n-1}{3n+2}$ converges to $\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis

$$a_n = \frac{2n-1}{3n+2}$$
Let $\epsilon > 0$,

Choose
$$n > \frac{7-6\epsilon}{9\epsilon},$$

Then,  $$\frac{7}{9n+6} < \epsilon$$

$$\implies \frac{2}{3}-\frac{2n-1}{3n+2} < \epsilon$$

How to proceed ?

Comment: Compute $|a_n - 2/3|$ ...

Comment: @MartinR i am not sure how to bring in absolute value here

Comment: Well, then start with $a_n -2/3$ ...

Comment: @MartinR $|a_n - 2/3| =  \frac{-7}{9n+6}$

Comment: Actually $|a_n - 2/3| =  \frac{7}{9n+6}$. And  $ \frac{7}{9n+6} < \frac 1n$.

Comment: @MartinR is my first and second step correct ?

Comment: How did you arrive at $\frac{7-6\epsilon}{9\epsilon}$ if you do not know how to answer the question?

Comment: @geetha290krm absolute value sign is making me confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get that you want to use the $\epsilon$ definition here. Recall the definition: a sequence $(a_n)$ is said to be convergent to $a$ if and only if $$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N_{\epsilon} \geq 1, \text{ such that } \forall n \geq N_{\epsilon}: |a_n -a | < \epsilon.$$

Basically, your task is to find $N_{\epsilon}$ that allows $|a_n -a | < \epsilon$ to happen for any $n \geq N_{\epsilon}$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and consider $a_n = \dfrac{2n-1}{3n+2}$, we claim that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \dfrac{2}{3}$. Take $N_{\epsilon} > \dfrac{7-6 \epsilon}{9 \epsilon}$. So if $n > N_{\epsilon}$ then
\begin{align}
|a_n -a | = \left|\dfrac{2n-1}{3n+2} - \dfrac{2}{3}\right| = \dfrac{7}{9n +6} < \dfrac{7}{9 N_{\epsilon} +6} < \epsilon.
\end{align}

**Edit:** We can take $N_{\epsilon} = \left\lfloor \dfrac{7-6 \epsilon}{9 \epsilon} \right\rfloor + 1$ where $ \lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function to guarantee that $N_{\epsilon}$ is an integer that's always greater than 1.

Comment: The equality $\frac{7}{9N_\epsilon+6}=\epsilon$ should be the inequality $\frac{7}{9N_\epsilon+6} < \epsilon$.